# Remove duplicate records from a three column file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am trying to remove some entries from a txt file containing 3 columns. The first two contains ID entries and the third one, contains its percentage as follows:

```
ID#3    ID#1    100.00
ID#4    ID#4    40.00
ID#4    ID#5    33.065
ID#5    ID#5    100.000    
ID#5    ID#4    33.065
ID#6    ID#6    100.000
```

I want to "remove" every entry with the same ID BUT ONLY WHEN the percentage is 100% so as the desired output will be like:

```
ID#3    ID#1    100.00    
ID#4    ID#4    40.00
ID#4    ID#5    33.065
ID#5    ID#4    33.065
```

I tried this:

```
cat file.txt | awk '$3!=100.0 && $1=$2 {print $1,$2}'
```

but I cant find a way to include the cases when the first two columns are not the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '($1==$2) && $NF==100{next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
($1==$2) && $NF==100{       ##Checking condition if $1(first field) equals to $2(2nd field) AND $NF(last field) equals 100 then do following.
  next                      ##next will SKIP all further statements from here.
}                           ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
1                           ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
' Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, is not what I am looking for. The output of your suggestion is the $1 = $2 = 100.00. What Im looking for is to REMOVE every entry that has  a format  $1 = $2 = 100.00 from my file.

Comment: @KGee, I have added a detailed explanation for above code too, in case of any queries lemme know.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '!($1==$2 && $3==100)' ip.txt
ID#3    ID#1    100.00
ID#4    ID#4    40.00
ID#4    ID#5    33.065
ID#5    ID#4    33.065
```

- `$1==$2` checks if first column same as second column
- `$3==100` checks if third column is `100`
- `&&` to check if both the conditions above are true
- `!($1==$2 && $3==100)` to invert the combined condition
- can also use `$1!=$2 || $3!=100` (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Also note that file can be passed directly to `awk` command. And not sure why you are using `{print $1,$2}` when the expected output shown contains three columns.